# How to glue center environment to the text?

Tags: glue

I have very often a situation when I want that the `center` environment is glued to the preceding text, something like that:

```
Some text
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
some commands
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Is it possible to make a general solution for that, for example defining new environment based on `center` or completely new environment to do the task?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: you could replace the `%` by `\nopagebreak`

Comment: I can confirm egreg's comment: `\nopagebreak` does not work.

Comment: hmph it could be made to work:-) @egreg can answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\center` environment uses `\trivlist` and issues an `\item` command, that adds `\@beginparpenalty`, which is usually −51. Thus a page break point is always available before `center`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lines=7]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{gluecenter}
 {\@beginparpenalty\@M\center}
 {\endcenter}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gluecenter}
This should stay
\end{gluecenter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `center` the centered line would be on a page by itself (the `\lipsum` paragraph has seven lines).

Another solution is to (ab)use `displaymath`, because a `tikzpicture` is independent on the mode it is called in.

```
Some text
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I decided for `gluecenter`, because I don't like to abuse things :)

Comment: @Pygmalion For a `tikzpicture` I'd go with `\[...\]`.

Comment: Could you, in couple of words, say why?

Comment: @Pygmalion The display math mechanism is *designed* not to add a page break point before it and exploiting this method for adding a graphic object that *must* stay there is not a real abuse.

Comment: It should be noted that `gluecenter` always leaves two text lines together with the picture, which is a plus compared to `\[`/`\]`

Comment: Your answer was extremely helpful.  But now I realised that few `center` environments should be glued **below** or **above and below**.  Is this also possible to do?  Shall I open another question or revise the current one?

Comment: @Pygmalion For below, it's a completely different matter.