# How to glue center environment to the trailing text?

Tags: glue

After getting the solution to my [first problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442839/how-to-glue-center-environment-to-the-text/442846) thanks to egreg, I have came across the second one: very often I am in a situation when I want that the `center` environment is glued (no page break) to the trailing text, something like that:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
some commands
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%
Some text
```

Is it possible to make a general solution for that, for example defining new environment based on center or completely new environment to do the task?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: What do you mean with  *glued* to the following text? To avoid the paragraph break if you leave an empty line?

Comment: @Johannes_B To avoid PAGE break.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the `\nopagebreak` macro?

Comment: The `center` environment probably allows a page break anyway, i would need to check.

Comment: @Johannes_B I've tried that already, doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\samepage{...}`.

```
\samepage{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
some commands
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%
Some text%
}% end of \samepage
```

If *Some text* itself should be allowed to break across pages, replace the `center` environment and use `\nopagebreak`.

```
{\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 some commands
 \end{tikzpicture}%
 \par
}\nopagebreak
%
Some text
```

Comment: +1 ... but [now I have to run](http://www.wisdompubs.org/book/yeti-catching-marmots) ;-)

Comment: @marmot oh! Run my little marmot, *runnnnnn!*

Comment: @marmot Nothing to fear: *"The Yeti [...] sees a marmot, grabs the hapless creature, and then sits on it—saving the delicious morsel for later. And then the Yeti sees another marmot and leaps up to snatch it while the first marmot makes a quick break for freedom. An image of bumbling, foolish effort."*

Comment: Mhm, it is alright, actually necessary, to split the following paragraph.  Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Pygmalion See updated solution